# Detecting onChange in Magento Admin with out need to call jQuery

Tags: admin, jquery

Below i code that i am using

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();


$j(document).ready(function(){
    $j( "#stone_theme" ).change(function() {
            new Ajax.Request("http://localhost/infoz/test.php", {
                method: 'Post',
                parameters: {"parameter_name":"value"},
                onComplete: function(transport) {
                    alert(transport.responseText);
                }
            });
    });
});
```

but i had to include jquery for it is there any way to do this with out calling jquery ??..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you're very close already as you're not using jQuery's ajax functions. You've (correctly) used Prototype's ajax objects.

So now what you need to do is remove the jQuery dependency by adding click handler from Prototype.js (the js lib that ships with Magento).

To do that you want to

```
document.observe('dom:loaded', function(){

    $('stone_theme').observe('change',function(e){
        new Ajax.Request("http://localhost/infoz/test.php", {
            method: 'Post',
            parameters: {"parameter_name":"value"},
            onComplete: function(transport) {
                alert(transport.responseText);
            }
        });
    });


});
```

Note that the `$` function for Prototype.js is essentially shorthand for `document.getElementById` - equivalent to the jQuery selector `$('#stone_theme')`;

Comment: $('stone_theme').observe('change',function(e){
 or     $('#stone_theme').observe('change',function(e){

Comment: *without* the # sign

Comment: thanks its working how can i get selected value of stone_theme dropdown i tried e.val but it give undefined value

Comment: e.target.value should do it